# Function to grab all windows and nested windows on a page

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote the following function which takes in a window and returns all nested windows on a webpage (I can get all the windows by calling the function with window.top). Is there a more elegant/efficient way to grab a reference to all the windows and child windows on the page? The function works, but I was having a hard time wrapping my head around writing it completely recursively (without the for loop) as the DOM tree is an n-ary tree, not binary.

```
function getNestedWindows(window) {
    var windows = [window];
    if (window.length === 0) {
      return windows;
    }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.length; i++) {
        windows = windows.concat(getNestedWindows(window[i]));
      }
    }
    return windows;
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: I want to know both the number of iframes on a site as well as try to measure the width and height of each frame.